# pandas style can't set background gradient on multiindex after dataframe division

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, multi-index, pandas-styles

I can do a pandas styles heatmap over a multi-index no problem:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('geyser').reset_index()

df['3m_duration'] = df.duration > 3

group_cols = ['kind', '3m_duration']

count_gpby = df[
    group_cols + ['index']
].groupby(
    group_cols
)

count_gpby.count().style.background_gradient(cmap ='Blues')
```

[image: first heatmap]

I can also divide a subset groupby by the total groupby to get a comparative rate/ratio per group:

```
df['binary'] = 'A'
df.loc[100:, 'binary'] = 'B'

subset_gpby = df[
    group_cols + ['index']
].loc[df.binary=='B'].groupby(
    group_cols
).count()

(subset_gpby / gpby).style.background_gradient(cmap ='Blues')
```

[image]

But then I try to combine these two "views" as two columns in the same multi-index dataframe so that I can see a raw count and a comparative ratio at the same time. This has no issue printing:

[image]

But it cant be displayed with the Pandas style heatmap background gradient because of "non-unique indices":

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-f82cbb6545e2> in <module>
----> 1 pd.concat([(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1).style.background_gradient(cmap ='Blues')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in style(self)
    959         from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
    960 
--> 961         return Styler(self)
    962 
    963     _shared_docs[

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py in __init__(self, data, precision, table_styles, uuid, caption, table_attributes, cell_ids, na_rep, uuid_len)
    161             data = data.to_frame()
    162         if not data.index.is_unique or not data.columns.is_unique:
--> 163             raise ValueError("style is not supported for non-unique indices.")
    164 
    165         self.data = data

ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices.
```

However,

```
pd.concat([(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1).index.value_counts()

> (short, False)    1
> (short, True)     1
> (long, True)      1
> (long, False)     1
> dtype: int64
```

shows that there's only one instance of each index, and the index is equal to the previous indices that render with no problem:

```
pd.concat([(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1).index == (subset_gpby / gpby).index

> array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Why does this error appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas, both the "Index", and "Columns" are of type [pd.Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html). For this reason, both axes can be referred to as an Index. The [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) object only works on uniquely indexed DataFrames (See other [limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Limitations) here), this includes *both* dimensions.

When [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)ing the two items we end up with multiple columns named 'index':

```
pd.concat([(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1)

                      index  index  # <- Note the duplicate column names
kind  3m_duration                 
long  False        1.000000      1
      True         0.631579    171
short False        0.635417     96
      True         0.500000      4
```

Since we don't have meaningful column names, we can simply pass `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (Note this only affects the axis of concatenation, `axis=1` in this case):

```
pd.concat([(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

                          0    1
kind  3m_duration               
long  False        1.000000    1
      True         0.631579  171
short False        0.635417   96
      True         0.500000    4
```

Or, as always, we can rename columns to be meaningful. However, we need something like [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) here since [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) would affect all columns named "index":

```
pd.concat(
    [(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1
).set_axis(['Subset gpby', 'gpby'], axis=1)

                   Subset gpby  gpby
kind  3m_duration                   
long  False           1.000000     1
      True            0.631579   171
short False           0.635417    96
      True            0.500000     4
```

Anyway we do it, we will be able to use `background_gradient` again since the column index is unique:

```
pd.concat(
    [(subset_gpby / gpby), gpby], axis=1, ignore_index=True
).style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues')
```

[image: Styled table with background gradient and renamed columns]

---

Setup used:

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

# Setup Data
df = sns.load_dataset('geyser').reset_index()
group_cols = ['kind', '3m_duration']
df['3m_duration'] = df['duration'].gt(3)
subset_df = df[[*group_cols, 'index']].copy()
# Build Count DataFrames
gpby = subset_df.groupby(group_cols).count()
subset_gpby = subset_df.loc[100:, :].groupby(group_cols).count()
```